# Obter CSS por JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Existe alguma forma de obter a lista de todo *CSS* aplicado a um elemento por *JavaScript*?

Exemplo:

Digamos que eu tenho o seguinte elemento *HTML*:

```
<div id="mega">Content</div>
```

Tenho também o *CSS*:

```
#mega {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Se eu quisesse tomar uma decisão baseada no *CSS* que está no elemento com o `id="mega"` para mudar ou não, é possível pegar essa lista de *CSS* que foi aplicada ao elemento por *JavaScript*?

Comment: Podes usar o `window.getComputedStyle(el)`, é isso que procuras?

Comment: Isso não será um problema XY ? Pode dar um exemplo do que está efetivamente a tentar fazer ?

Comment: @Isac, nesse caso eu realmente queria saber se tem como obter esses dados do CSS por JavaScript porque sabendo o formato de retorno sei o que preciso verificar, mas anteriormente eu queria tomar a decisão se um elemento já estava com o `display: block` para colocar o `display: none` acabei percebendo que quando estava fazendo isso o retorno da verificação era `undefined`, contornei o problema na época, mas aceito indicação de leitura, caso tenha algo a compartilhar.

Comment: Sim tem sempre forma, mas o mais comum é aceder ao atributo que quer diretamente. No caso de `display` por exemplo, o mais comum será aceder direto com `if (el.style.display == "block") {`. Foi exatamente isso que me levou a perguntar se não seria um problema XY

Comment: @Isac, mas nesse caso o `el.style.display == "block"` sempre dará `false` pois a não ser que o atributo tenha sido definido pelo JavaScript essa condição não acessa o atributo definido no arquivo CSS. Tente  `console.log(el.style.display)` definindo o `display: block` no CSS.

Comment: Sim, de facto depende um pouco de como foi definido para saber como utilizar. Se foi definido apenas no CSS e não foi aplicado inline no `style` ou pelo JS tem de facto de usar `computedStyle`, mas continua a ser +- direto: `if (getComputedStyle(el).display == "block") {`. E apenas no `if` precisa do computed, depois a troca de display seria no `style.display` na mesma.

Comment: @Isac, Isso mesmo! Por isso que foi bom saber dessa função de um modo geral! Obrigado.

Comment: Só para ajudar um pouco mais pode até tornar isso tudo num ternário, assim: `el.style.display = (getComputedStyle(el).display == "block") ? "none":"block";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar o [`window.getComputedStyle(el)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), isso vai dar algo semelhante a um objeto onde podes ler as suas propriedades para saber quais os estilos aplicados. Ele é bem grande, pois refere todas as propriedades, mas ficas com a informação que procuras...

Podes usar assim:

```
var backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor;
```

Exemplo:

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(p);
console.log('Cor de fundo:', styles.backgroundColor);

// para teres tudo podes fazer assim:
var css = Object.keys(styles).reduce(
  (obj, prop) => (prop.match(/\D/) && (obj[prop] = styles[prop]), obj), {}
);
console.log(css);
```

```css
p {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: blue;">Teste</p>
```

Isso irá gerar algo assim:

```
{
  "alignContent": "normal",
  "alignItems": "normal",
  "alignSelf": "auto",
  "alignmentBaseline": "auto",
  "all": "",
  "animation": "none 0s ease 0s 1 normal none running",
  "animationDelay": "0s",
  "animationDirection": "normal",
  "animationDuration": "0s",
  "animationFillMode": "none",
  "animationIterationCount": "1",
  "animationName": "none",
  "animationPlayState": "running",
  "animationTimingFunction": "ease",
  "backfaceVisibility": "visible",
  "background": "rgb(0, 128, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box",
  "backgroundAttachment": "scroll",
  "backgroundBlendMode": "normal",
  "backgroundClip": "border-box",
  "backgroundColor": "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
  "backgroundImage": "none",
  "backgroundOrigin": "padding-box",
  "backgroundPosition": "0% 0%",
  "backgroundPositionX": "0%",
  "backgroundPositionY": "0%",
  "backgroundRepeat": "repeat",
  "backgroundRepeatX": "",
  "backgroundRepeatY": "",
  "backgroundSize": "auto",
  "baselineShift": "0px",
  "blockSize": "-20px",
  "border": "0px none rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "borderBottom": "0px none rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "borderBottomColor": "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "borderBottomLeftRadius": "0px",
  "borderBottomRightRadius": "0px",
  "borderBottomStyle": "none",
  "borderBottomWidth": "0px",
  "borderCollapse": "separate",
  "borderColor": "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "borderImage": "none",
  etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Ex:

```
function ObterCSS(element){
  var css = '';
  var o = getComputedStyle(element);
  for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
    css+=o[i] + ':' + o.getPropertyValue(o[i])+';';
  }
  return css;
}
```

Comment: Gostei do retorno que essa função dá. Obrigado.